# $f(z)= (s-1) \zeta(s)$. Prove that $\log |f(0)|=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am reading Balazard, Saias and Yor Paper on the RH where they consider a function$$  f(z)= (s-1) \zeta(s)$$  where $ \ s=\frac{1}{1-z}$ and $\zeta $ denotes the Zeta function

$$\text{Claim:} \qquad \log|f(0)|=0$$
**My Try**-

$$\lim_{s \to 1} (s-1)\zeta(s)=1$$
$$\lim_{z \to 0} f(z)=1$$
$f$ is continuous at $0$ as it is analytic near $0$
$$f(0)=\lim_{z \to 0} f(z)=1$$
$$\log|f(0)|=0$$
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Thanks for the edit. Please answer. Am i correct?

Comment: @Michael Hardy Thanks for the edit. Please answer. Any mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No mistake, the reasoning is fine.

$(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is analytic at $s=1$ and $1/(1-z)$ is analytic at $0$ whence the composition is analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: But how is f continuous at 0?

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer.

Comment: How is the composition analytic at 0?

Comment: I got it. Thanks reuns.